# Grails Easygrid plugin: How to set an initial filter?

Tags: grails, grid, filtering

I've a grid defined like this:

**Controller:**

```
def invoicesJQGridGrid = {
    dataSourceType 'gorm'
    domainClass Invoice
    gridImpl 'jqgrid'
    columns {
        id {
            type 'id'
        }
    customerId
    date
    amount
    address
    paymentInfo
    paymentDate
    }
}
```

**GSP:**

```
<grid:grid id='invoicesGrid' name='invoicesJQGrid'>
</grid:grid>
```

I need to set an initial filter on customerId column to show only the invoices of a specific customer
and this filter has to be applied to each query for example other filtering or sorting applied by the user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Theres's a closure called 'initialCriteria'

see: https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid_example/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/example/AuthorController.groovy
the 'authorDatatablesOverBillGrid' grid - which displays only authors with over a billion sales.

You can access any injected service or params, request, session, etc in that closure.